# How to ignore fields in search while being able to search using the API?

Tags: javascript, datatables

My table contains thre columns; "name", "description" and "status". I have a dropdown field which filters the table on the status column. Essentially:

```
$('.js-status-dropdown').dropdown({
    onChange: function (value) {
        $('#dt').DataTable().column('status:name').search(value).draw();
    }
});
```

This works, but the problem is the standard free-text search input field includes the status field in the free-text search.

Setting `searchable: false` on the status field causes the dropdown to stop working since Datatable ignores it.

```
{
    data: 'status',
    name: 'status',
    searchable: false // Stops table.column().search(value) from working :-(
}
```

Ideally, the (standard) free-text search field should ignore the stuatus column, but the dropdown code should still be working.

Comment: more code is needed

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Take a look at http://code.buzzword-cloud.com/post/2017/05/02/datatables-column-searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

1. Set the column to `searchable: false`. This makes the table ignore this column in free text searches.
2. Add a custom search which uses the **original row data**, `settings.aoData`, instead of the data array (it doesn't contain the column because of 1.)
3. Redraw the table when the filter dropdown changes.

Code:

```
    $('#dt').DataTable(defaults)
            .on('init.dt', statusHandling);

    function statusHandling(e, settings, processing) {

        // Redraw table on dropdown status change
        $('.js-status-dropdown').dropdown({
            onChange: function (value) {
                $(options.table).DataTable().draw();
            }
        });

        // Our custom search function which adds an AND 'status = foo' condition
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
            function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                var input = $('input[name=status]').val().toLowerCase();
                // Use original data instead of 'data' because status is not searchable
                var status = settings.aoData[dataIndex]['_aData']['status'];
                return status.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) === 0;
            }
        );
    }
```